# c++ linux library for creating an xml and reading from an xml (serialize/ deserialize)

Tags: c++, xml, xml-serialization

I am working in Ubuntu. I have a .h file with a class and a lot of nested classes. I would like to create an XML file from an object. Can someone please give me a library that creates XML files, serializes, and deserializes objects? I am compiling with g++.

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with Facebook?

Comment: does it have to be XML, else you could use boost::serialization.

Comment: yes i need to create an xml, because i'll receive from the server xml files

Answer (score 3):

Try [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

But it seems like you want to serialize and desirialize an object from and to XML. [Boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) might come in handy. it also supports serialization from and to XML.

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/example/demo_xml.cpp) you can find an example for Boost::serialization with XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle XML in C++ you may have a look at these projects

http://xmlsoft.org/

http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/

Answer (score 0):

A super-lightweight, simple xml library is [pugixml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/).

Though keep in mind that C++ does not have the reflection capabilities that .NET has. No library will generate the serialization/deserialization code for you (which I guess you hoped for).

Comment: Sorry, there *ARE* tools that generate XML (de)serialization code (see posts).

Comment: @Alex, perhaps my wording is a bit ambiguous. What I meant is there is no *library* that will generate serialization code. I wanted to point out the lack of reflection in C++ which makes this hard.

Comment: No offense, but it did not answer the OP's question and possibly adds more confusion to discuss libraries that do not do what the OP is looking for. You're back to 0 usefulness to make you happy :)

Comment: @Alex, my answer is very similar to others in the thread. OP asked for a library that "creates XML files, serializes, and deserializes objects". Many people, including myself posted XML libraries and pointed out that a library on its own will not do what he probably hopes for.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't serialize with XML (which I consider a feature, personally), but [Google protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) does a good job of serializing (in a binary format) objects that are defined in the `.proto` language.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explore the [XML Data Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_data_binding). The main idea is that given an xml schema the data binding software generates a class hierarchy corresponding to the schema, and the code to serialize / unserialize (called marshal / unmarshal). There are several tools that can do this, [gsoap](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/) is a free one, xmlSpy is one of the commercial ones.

Comment: hi, can you give me an example of create/serialize an xml object deserialize an xml object using gsoap plz

Comment: Our design changed so I didn't do it myself in the end, but spent some short time reading the manual. There is a tutorial with examples on the site or in the download.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is an [XML data binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_data_binding) for C++. There are several tools for what you want to do, see e.g. [XML Data Binding Tools](http://xmldatabinding.org/XmlDataBindingTools.aspx). I've used [gSOAP](http://www.genivia.com/dev.html) for several C++ projects, including starting from C++ files with classes which is really nice (other tools force you to start from XML schemas or WSDLs). With gSOAP I have been able to generate XML schemas and XML, see e.g. [map C/C++ types to XML schema](http://www.genivia.com/doc/databinding/html/index.html#toxsd).