# c++ how to create write an xml and how to read from it?

Tags: c++, xml, serialization

I am working in Ubuntu. I would like to create serialize an object. Because I didn't find any library in c++ that can help me, I am going to write the XML by my own. I would like to ask how to do that. It is ok if I say:

`std::string xml = "<?xml..."+"<name>%s</name>\n"+"<birthdate>%d</birthdate>"...+name,date;`

Can you please tell me if it's ok? One more question : how to do the deserialization? Is there a library that reads an xml and prints the values that you would like? I am working in c++ code. THX!

EDIT:

```
.h
//code
class people
{
public:
people();
std::string name;
std::string birthday;
int number;
};

.cpp
//code
people *p = new people();
p.name="me";
p.birthday=11;
p.number=1;
```

I would like to create an XML file based on *p. How to do it with libxml++ or any library? After this I would also want the deserialization of course.

Comment: Have a look at iksemel; http://code.google.com/p/iksemel/ which are actually C libs. You can have a look at http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/html/ too

Comment: Several xml libraries were mentioned on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977358/c-linux-library-for-creating-an-xml-and-reading-from-an-xml-serialize-deseria) any of them are better than writing by hand. And no, what you are trying here does not work, but a compiler is faster to tell you that than StackOverflow. First: read, learn. Then: program. Not the other way around. Just my two cents.

Comment: None of them is helpful. I want to create an xml from an object and that's all. I don;t want to write code in the class that i want to serialize.

Comment: @Mayank can you give me plz a link where i can find some c++ code examples with libxml++? THX

Comment: And how is writing the XML by hand any better? As I told in my answer to that question, C++ won't magically generate the serialization code for you.

Comment: In the same page you can find few links. On clicking DOM parser you get this: http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/html/ar01s02.html#id2504579

Comment: ALSO can i use libxml++ for deserialize an xml?

Comment: @just me: google is your friend. Besides. you can always browse your earlier questions to find links to sample code

Comment: If you don't want to (or cannot) put code in the object, you can always create a helper function that returns the corresponding XML for the object. But you will still be better of using an XML library like libxml, Qt or whatever you choose.

Comment: Your edit hasn't changed anything. The answers in the other question are still valid. (that is, as soon as you make your example compilable.)

Comment: how can i do that? Can you please tell me? Can you please create an xml based on my example?

Answer (score 2):

For a C++ serialization library see [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) as per @Begemoth 's comment see [Boost tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion) - code does not have to be added to the class.

Comment: I can't use Boost because it does not serialize an object, I don;t want to add code in the class. I just want to serialize an object and thst'a all

Comment: You can implement serialization as free functions.  But if you want to automagically serialize any class into XML C++ is not a tool for the job.

Comment: boost::serialize serializes and object. It has been designed for it, and nothing else... And as begemoth says, you can use free functions to separate the serialisation from the class (IMHO it's a usualy better to keep everything together)

Comment: how can i do that? please give me an example. I did put a small code in my edit question

Comment: [Boost.Serializaton Tutorial -> Non Intrusive Version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion)

Comment: Seriously? If you want to become a better developper, then you'll need first to learn to search and read by yourself. The tutorial is pretty straightfoward http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: OK,THX I WILL CHECK:). THX A LOT!