# Create an xml from an object 

Tags: c++, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ linux library for creating an xml and reading from an xml (serialize/ deserialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977358/c-linux-library-for-creating-an-xml-and-reading-from-an-xml-serialize-deseria)

HI,
I am working in Ubuntu. I would like to create an xml from am object
I have this:

```
Class me
{
    std::tring name;
    int age;
};

main()

me *p = new me();

p->age=12;
p->name="dina";
```

How can I create an xml. I would like to have

```
<data>
    <name>p->name</name>
    <age>p->age</age>
</data>
```

Comment: I tried fixing the formatting... but I gave up because it didn't seem to make any sense...

Comment: thx a lot! I found an example with tinyxml and i would like to use it. can you tell me how to install thelibrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [TinyXml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/); it allows a Document Object Model (DOM) to be constructed with your object attributes and then saved to file.

Comment: can you tell me how to install tinyxml using apt-get install? thx

Comment: A quick look with a popular brand of search engine revealed [libtinyxml-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libtinyxml-dev) is the package.

Comment: @just me: It's so tiny that you are supposed to compile the 4 C++ source files in with your project, however I have recently compiled it as a static library to make it easier.